# JavaScript variable in link

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

In my PHP code I have an link

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL('BookController/delete/') . [INSERT ID]?>">
```

In my JavaScript file I have a varriable called ID,

```
var Id = event.target.getAttribute('deleteid');
```

this varriable needs to be inserted to the link. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Get a reference to the element, and set its href attribute to the new value you want it to be.

Comment: Is the link related to the `event`? How would you reference the anchor?

Comment: if  I do this then `<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL('BookController/delete/') 25?>">`. No JS neded

Answer (score 0):

Two cases:

**When the ID is known at the server rendering time**

You can inject the Id right into the rendering.

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL('BookController/delete/') . $bookId>">
```

**When the ID is chosen at runtime by the user**

A. Generate the dom element link dynamicaly and insert it to the dom:

```
var $newLink = $( "<a href='BookController/delete/" + bookId + "'></a>" ),
$( "page" ).append($newLink);
```

B. Or handle the browser redirection in javascript instead of letting the `<a>` do it for you

Html:

```
<a id="myBookLink">myBook</a>
```

Script:

```
$("#myBookLink").click(function () {
   window.location.href = '/BookController/delete/' + someBookId;
});
```